# OpenGL program with Intel HD and NVidia GPU usage

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, gpu, nvidia

I am new in OpenGL and I want somebody to explain me how the program uses GPU.

I have an array of triangles(class that contains 3 points). Here is the code that draw them( I know these functions are depricated).

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for(int i=0; i<trsize; ++i){
    glVertex3d((GLdouble)trarr[i].p1().x(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p1().y(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p1().z());
    glVertex3d((GLdouble)trarr[i].p2().x(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p2().y(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p2().z());
    glVertex3d((GLdouble)trarr[i].p3().x(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p3().y(), (GLdouble)trarr[i].p3().z());
}
glEnd();
```

And i also use depricated functions for rotating, transforming, etc.

When the size of array is bigger than 50k, the program works very slow.
I tried to use only Intel HD or only NVidia gtx860M (the default NVidia Program allows to choose GPU) but they both works very slow. Maybe Intel HD works even a bit faster.

So, why there is no difference between these two GPUs?
And will the program work faster with using shaders?

Comment: In short you're limited by your CPU, namely the function call and usermode→kernelmode context switching overhead your process has to hop through for every couple of these calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the size of array is bigger than 50k, the program works very slow.

The major bottleneck when drawing in intermediate mode is, that all your vertices have to be transferred in every frame from your programs memory to the GPU memory. The bus between GPU and CPU is limited in the amout of data it can transfer, so the best guess is, that 50k triangles are simply more than the bus can transport. Another problem is, that the driver has to process all the commands you send him on the CPU, which can also be a big overhead.

> So, why there is no difference between these two GPUs?

There is (in general) a huge performance difference between the Intel HD card and a NVIDIA card, but the bus between them might be the same.

> And will the program work faster with using shaders?

It will not benefit directly from the user of shaders, but definitely from storing the vertices once on the gpu memory (see VBO/VAO). The second improvement is, that you can render the whole VBO using only one draw call, which decreases the amount of instructions the cpu has to handle.

Answer (score 2):

The probable bottleneck is looping over the vertices, accessing the array and pulling out the vertex data **50000 times per render** then sending the data to the GPU for rendering.

Using a VBO would indeed be faster and compresses the cost of extracting the data and sending it to the GPU to once on initialization.

Even using a user memory buffer would speed it up because you won't be calling 50k functions but the driver can just do a memcopy of the relevant data.

Comment: What does 'user memory buffer' mean? I didn't find anything associated with OpenGL in google.

Comment: @user3051029 it's what happens when you bind 0 to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` then the offsets are in user memory.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the same performance with two GPUs that have substantially different performance potential certainly suggests that your code is CPU limited. But I very much question some of the theories about the performance bottleneck in the other answers/comments.

- Some simple calculations suggest that memory bandwidth should not come into play at all. With 50,000 triangles, with 3 vertices each, and 24 bytes per vertex, you're looking at 3,600,000 bytes of vertex data per frame. Say you're targeting 60 frames/second, this is a little over 200 MBytes/second. That's less than 1% of the memory bandwidth of a modern PC.
- The most practical implementation of immediate mode on a modern GPU is for drivers to collect all the data into buffers, and then submit it all at once when a buffer fills up. So there's no need for a lot of kernel calls, and the data for each vertex is certainly not sent to the GPU separately.

Driver overhead is most likely the main culprit. With 50,000 triangles, and 3 API calls per triangle, this is 150,000 API calls per frame, or 9 million API calls/second if you're targeting 60 frames/second. That's a lot! For each of these calls, you'll have:

- Looping and array accesses in your own code.
- The actual function call.
- Argument passing.
- State management and logic in the driver code.
- etc.

One important aspect that makes this much worse than it needs to be: You're using `double` values for your coordinates. That doubles the amount of data that needs to be passed around compared to using `float` values. And since the OpenGL vertex pipeline operates in single precision (*), the driver will have to convert all the values to `float`.

I suspect that you could get a significant performance improvement even with using the deprecated immediate mode calls if you started using `float` for all your coordinates (both your own storage, and for passing them to OpenGL). You could also use the version of the `glVertex*()` call that takes a single argument with a pointer to the vector, instead of 3 separate arguments. This would be `glVertex3fv()` for `float` vectors.

Making the move to VBOs is of course the real solution. It will reduce the number of API calls by orders of magnitude, and avoid any data copying as long as the vertex data does not change over time.

(*) OpenGL 4.1 adds support for `double` vertex attributes, but they require the use of specific API functions, and only make sense if single precision floats really are not precise enough.